# How can we send more than 10 textual custom parameters with custom event to Firebase analytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

My app requirement is to send more than 10 textual custom parameter to Firebase analytics but in Firebase analytics console is not permitting more than 10 textual parameter per project.

How can we track our custom event that is required more than 10 textual custom parameters?